# Regex string for sample strings

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regex for below strings.

```
string: Some () Text (1)
I want to capture 'Some () Text' and '1'

string: Any () Text
I want to capture 'Any () Text' and '0'
```

I came up with the following regex to capture 'text' and 'count' but it does not match the 2nd ex above.

```
@"(?<text>.+)\((?<count>\d+)\)
```

c#:

```
string pattern = @"(?<text>.+)\((?<count>\d+)\)";
Match m = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
count = 0;
text = "";
if (m.Success)
{
    text = m.Groups["text"].Value.Trim();
    int.TryParse(m.Groups["count"].Value, out count);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the group optional:

```
string pattern = @"^(?<text>.+?)(\((?<count>\d+)\))?$";
Match m = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
count = 0;
text = "";
if (m.Success)
{
    text = m.Groups["text"].Value.Trim();

    if(m.Groups["count"].Success) {
        int.TryParse(m.Groups["count"].Value, out count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @hIpPy: Really fixed now, and [here's proof](http://ideone.com/H2ab1). Maybe next time don't say your code already works for the first test case if it doesn't ;)

Comment: minitech, it works. :) thanks. my regex works for 1st and not for 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`(?<group_text>Some Text) (?:\((?<group_count>\d+)\)|(?<group_count>))`

**update**

There is really too many ways to go here given the information you provide.
This could be the totally flexible version.

```
(?<group_text>
   (?:
       (?! \s* \( \s* \d+ \s* \) )
       [\s\S]
   )*
)
\s*
(?:
    \( \s* (?<group_count>\d+ ) \s* \)
)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp solution:

```
var s = "Some Text (1)";
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @"(?<text>[^(]+)\((?<d>[^)]+)\)");
var matches = match.Groups; 
if(matches["text"].Success && matches["d"].Success) {
    int n = int.Parse(matches["d"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("text = {0}, number = {1}", match.Groups["text"].Value, n);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("NOT FOUND");
}
```

`.Split()` solution:

```
var parts = s.Split(new char[] { '(', ')'});
var text = parts[0];
var number = parts[1];
int n; 
if(parts.Length >= 3 int.TryParse(number, out n)) {
    Console.WriteLine("text = {0}, number = {1}", text,n);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("NOT FOUND");
}
```

Output:

```
text = Some Text , number = 1
text = Some Text , number = 1
```